# Pass regex to variable (angular)

Tags: angularjs, regex, razor

I have such a code `ng-init="validationRegex = '@RegularExpression.expression'"` where `RegularExpression.expression` is c# string variable = `"(\w+\/|\w+\\)+(\w+)\.\w+"`. I want to pass variable value to angular controller using `ng-init`. But in the end I get `(w+/|w+\)+(w+).w+`. How can I get right value?

Comment: `c# string variable = "(\w+\/|\w+\\)+(\w+)\.\w+"` translates to this `(w+\|w+\)+(w+).w+` inside a variable. Try `"(\\w+/|\\w+\\)+(\\w+)\\.\\w+ "` which translates to `(\w+/|\w+\)+(\w+)\.\w+`

Comment: If it is to compile, the double quote string would be `"(\\w+/|\\w+\\\\)+(\\w+)\\.\\w+ "`, but still not sure what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your C# code is actually: `@"(\w+\/|\w+\\)+(\w+)\.\w+"`. The `@` avoids needing the evil escaped escape.

You will likely need to use the evil escaped escape in this case. Note that you don't need to escape the `/` if you are putting it directly in a string (if you are using it how I think you are). You can also use braces to minimize the escaping. So you can take this regex:

```
(\w+/|\w+\\)+(\w+)[.]\w+
```

and pass it through [regex planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to get this:

```
"(\\w+/|\\w+\\\\)+(\\w+)[.]\\w+"
```

I would not recommend manual conversion since you already have an escaped backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Double escape the string using:

```
@RegularExpression.expression.Replace(@"\", @"\\")
```

When it comes through on the JavaScript side it will be singly-escaped again.